# Two quantities visualization

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

I have a problem figuring out how to visualize two simple quantities using R. I want to compare their size by visualizing two proportional spatial figures next to each other and the size proportional to their volume, height or whatever. E.g. I have two numbers 45 and 15, after my code execution I would get two spatial figures, but first is three times bigger. 
https://visual.ly/blog/45-ways-to-communicate-two-quantities/ <- I want to do something like in this article example no.26 "Volumes". 
Figures could be like cone, cube or 3d pie. Is is possible to realize that using ggplot2 or any other package?

Answer (score 0):

Having some example data to work with would make it easier for people to help you here, imo. Without that I can suggest looking at [plot3D](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/vignettes/plot3D.pdf) or [rgl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html). hth.

Answer (score 0):

> Is is possible to realize that using ggplot2 or any other package?

Yes, it is possible, although, in general, not advisable.

If I may suggest, instead of cubes, cones and 3D pie charts it’d be better to use simple dot plots.

[image: dot plot]